# Why all layers shows on top (in layout) in OrCAD?

Tags: layout, orcad

I'm in trouble with Orcad Layout Plus 10.3.0.

All layers (SST, SSB, BOT, ...) shows on top when i generate gerber files, and view them with Gerbtool. But everything looks ok, when i open the .max file in Layout.

I hope that i don't need to create the PCB again, because i need to send it for fabrication tomorrow. Any ideas?

**Update:** Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried OrCAD support?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't merge the layers in GerbTool?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>From your description, it sounds like the gerber files show up in a wrong Z-order in GerbTool.  That doesn't sound like a sign of a problem, which would manifest itself during PCB fabrication, as long ans you correctly indicate to the fab which gerber file corresponds to which layer.</strike>

Comment: Here is a screenshot from my gerbtool [link](http://wtrns.fr/TjpqEiIX2W6Sygg)

Comment: @Adrian  I take it back.  You do have a problem, which would manifest itself in the fabricated board, obviously.  It's good that you've posted the screenshot.  What were your steps, which made OrCAD generate that gerber?

Comment: Options -> Post Process Settings. Here, i selected .TOP, .BOT, .SMT, and .SMB. Right click on the selected ones, and entered properties. Here i've enabled 'Extended Gerber' format, and enabled all options too. (Keep drill holes open, create drill files, overwrite existing files and enable for post processing). Ok and close. Now in Auto -> Run post processor. I'm following these steps everytime i need to create Gerbers, and always worked ok. Anyways, i redid the PCB again, but is good to know why that happened. Sorry answerring so late.

Comment: @Adrian  I've tried your steps with my OrCAD 10.5 and one of my layouts.  Got normal gerbers.  If you upload your problematic .MAX file and post a link.  I'll take a look at it.  You could also try [this place](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/OrCADexchange).  You could mirror your question there.

Comment: I don't have that .MAX file anymore. Sorry, and thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an option (same in Altium) to have a layer included with all layers. This was intended for outlines, legal notices, coupons, etc... looks like you have that enabled for all layers. I don't remember where it is located in the menu tree in OrCAD since I don't use OrCAD daily anymore.

Comment: I just noticed this as an old unanswered question, perhaps you should either update or delete the answer? Minus the struck out text it seems a little short on detail ;).

Comment: @PeterJ  I would have deleted the answer back in the day, if not for insightful comments under it.  The answer itself is incorrect, but it provides a starting point for the comments.  That's why I haven't deleted the answer back in the day.